# How to remove partial redundent patterns in each raws?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file like this:

```
reference   25038   A   G   39134   1   TPPH54  TPPH49  TPPH50  TPPHL51 TPPH52  TPPH53  TPPH55  p.Thr10198Thr
reference   77940   T   C   5131    1   TPPH54  TPPH49  p.Asn898Asp
reference   77940   T   C   5131    1   TPPH29  TPPH30  TPPH32  p.Gly48Gly
```

and I would like to get:

```
reference   25038   A   G   39134   1   TPPH54  p.Thr10198Thr
reference   77940   T   C   5131    1   TPPH54  p.Asn898Asp
reference   77940   T   C   5131    1   TPPH29  p.Gly48Gly
```

How to remove in awk/sed/grep patterns after the first one (always $7) all those having the same beggining??

I was thinking something like:

- only print the 7 first columns and the last one

  paste <(awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7}' file) <(awk '{print ????}' file-tmp) > file-final

but I don't know how to get the last one because the number can be different at each raw

- or 'scan' the file until having 'TPPH' beginning expression, keep the first one and remove the other ones for each raw. I'm not sure how to do it

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you care about preserving the white space between columns? If so - is your input separated by tabs or multiple blanks or are they fixed-width fields.

Comment: Look up what `$NF` means . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E ':a;s/(([^ \t]*[ \t]+){6}TPPH[0-9]+)[ \t]+TPPH[^ \t]*[ \t]+/\1\t/;ta' input_file
reference   25038   A   G   39134   1   TPPH54  p.Thr10198Thr
reference   77940   T   C   5131    1   TPPH54  p.Asn898Asp
reference   77940   T   C   5131    1   TPPH29  p.Gly48Gly
```

Comment: awesome, better than "sed -E 's/(([^ \t]*[ \t]+){7}).*[ \t]+/\1 /' file". Thank you!

Comment: @vmicrobio Indeed. I failed to read the question correctly the first time. Glad it works for you.

Answer (score 8):

You can just do:

```bash
awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $NF}' file | column -t
reference  25038  A  G  39134  1  TPPH54  p.Thr10198Thr
reference  77940  T  C  5131   1  TPPH54  p.Asn898Asp
reference  77940  T  C  5131   1  TPPH29  p.Gly48Gly
```

Here `column -t` has been used for tabular display only.

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples in GNU `awk` please try following `awk` code. Using `match` function of `awk` here in which using regex to capture the required part which further creates 2 capturing groups and saving them into array named arr with index of 1,2 and so on. Then printing their value as per required output.

```bash
awk '
match($0,/^(\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+).*\s+(\S+)/,arr){
  print arr[1],arr[2]
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your rapid answer! It's not working because of 'awk: line 2: syntax error at or near ,'. I'm not sure to understand arr, arr1 and arr2 in your code

Comment: @vmicrobio, have written on mobile so couldn't test it but this should work IMHO. Could you please do confirm if you have copied it completely please, let me know cheers.

Comment: I have copied it completely but still have this synthax error at line 2

Comment: @vmicrobio, ohh extremely sorry there was a typo, I fixed it and tested in my GNU `awk` it worked fine. Please check my updated one once and let me know how it goes?

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\S+/\n&/8g;s/\n.*\n//;s/\n//' file
```

Insert newlines before the 8th and subsequent fields.

Remove everything between the first and last newlines.

If there were no extra fields, remove the unwanted newline.

---

Alternative:

```
sed -E 's/^((\S+\s+){7})((\S+)\s*)*/\1\4/' file
```

Keep the first seven fields and their space delimiters and retain the last field.

N.B. The last opportunity for a back reference is kept when the `*` quantifier is used in conjunction with grouping.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` to print the last field, you can use `$NF`

As your example data does not contain TPPH before the 7th field, you can split and concat the fields:

```
awk '$7~/^TPPH/{split($0,a,$7);print a[1], $7, $NF}' file
```

Output

```
reference   25038   A   G   39134   1    TPPH54 p.Thr10198Thr
reference   77940   T   C   5131    1    TPPH54 p.Asn898Asp
reference   77940   T   C   5131    1    TPPH29 p.Gly48Gly
```

---

**Note** that if you have exactly 7 columns and you print `$7` AND `$NF` you will print the same value twice.

In that case you can only print the last field it there are more than 7 fields:

```
awk '$7~/^TPPH/{split($0,a,$7);print a[1], $7 (NF==7?"" : OFS $NF)}' file
```